# Strange boost cpp_Int behaviour when using auto type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I just noticed some really strange behaviour when using auto to store the result of a boost cpp_int operation

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

int main() {
    using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
    cpp_int a = 1, b = 10 * a, d;
    auto c = 10 * a;
    d = c;
    std::cout << b << " " << c << " " << d << "\n";
}
```

which outputs:

```
10 0 0
```

instead of:

```
10 10 10
```

can anybody explain this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7089b244b558d930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`boost::multiprecision`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) uses [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) in an attempt to avoid computing intermediate results (the linked Boost page has a section explaining the reasons for doing so).

Because of that, the type of `c` in the following expression is not `cpp_int`

```
auto c = 10 * a;  // c is some internal implementation defined type
```

You can confirm this by [comparing the types of say `a` and `c`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb306bc1a4b42a5b).

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(c)>().pretty_name();
```

The Boost introduction even specifically mentions the pitfall of using `auto` to store an expression template

> One other potential pitfall that's only possible in C++11: you should never store an expression template using:
>
> ```
>  auto my_expression = a + b - c;
> ```
>
> unless you're absolutely sure that the lifetimes of `a`, `b` and `c` will outlive that of `my_expression`.

In your case, one of the operands is a literal, which seems to affect the result of converting the expression template to `cpp_int` even though the lifetime of `c` matches that of `a`. What happens exactly is difficult to say without delving deeper into the implementation of `operator*`, but suffice to say that you're doing something you shouldn't be, and most likely your example has undefined behavior.

You can fix the problem in several ways, beginning with use `cpp_int` instead of `auto`. Or cast the result of the expression template to `cpp_int`.

```
auto c = cpp_int(10 * a);
```

Or store the `10` in a `cpp_int`; then the caveat mentioned in the Boost documentation applies, and your example produces the expected result.

```
cpp_int a = 1, b = 10 * a, d, e = 10;
auto c = e * a;
```

Comment: Thank you, very good answer. I already knew everything except the most important part, that the lifetime of the operands must outlast the lifetime of the returned expression. The returned garbage makes sense now.